# HTML input type file taking multiple clicks in chrome

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML input element

```
<input name="file_image" type="file" 
       class="chosen_file" 
       style="width:202px;color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);display: inline;" 
       id="imgUpload" 
       onchange="imgUploadValidation();" 
       accept="image/*" />
```

Here, in chrome browser when I click the `Choose file` button multiple times, the file selection window also pops up multiple times. Like, when I click the button 3 times then a window pops up and after I click the cancel button another window pops up and so on. This problem is only in chrome browser though. Any idea ?